# Slow TVF execution using variables vs constants

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a long complex query that I've broken down into TVF for easier maintenance and to create base data that other reports are based on. However, it seems that when I parameterise input the query takes much longer to execute; the top query executes in ~3 seconds, the second in 40 seconds.

I thought this may be due to parameter sniffing, though these are inline TVFs so I'm not sure how relevant that is. I've tried wrapping in a stored proc for testing and explicitly declaring the params as `DATETIME`, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

```
DECLARE @Month int = 4
DECLARE @year int = 2015

DECLARE @startDate DateTime, @endDate DateTime

SELECT @startDate = Dateadd(mm, ( @year - 1900 ) * 12 + @month - 1, 0 )
SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, Dateadd(mm, ( @year - 1900 ) * 12 + @month, 0 ))

/* Constants */
SELECT
    *,
    DATEADD(MINUTE, ((CONVERT(DECIMAL, Mileage) / [Days]) / 56) * 60, '1900-01-01') EstDrivingTimeDay,
    DATEADD(MINUTE, duration / [days], '1900-01-01') EstTimeOnSiteDay,
    DATEADD(MINUTE, ((CONVERT(DECIMAL, Mileage) / [Days]) / 56) * 60, '1900-01-01') + DATEADD(MINUTE, duration / [days], '1900-01-01') TotalWorkingTime
FROM
    GetDriverCreditsByMonthYearBaseViewTrips('2015-04-01', '2015-04-30' )

/* Stored Proc Wrapper */
EXEC DriverTripsByMonthYear @month, @year

/* Params in SQL */
SELECT
    *,
    DATEADD(MINUTE, ((CONVERT(DECIMAL, Mileage) / [Days]) / 56) * 60, '1900-01-01') EstDrivingTimeDay,
    DATEADD(MINUTE, duration / [days], '1900-01-01') EstTimeOnSiteDay,
    DATEADD(MINUTE, ((CONVERT(DECIMAL, Mileage) / [Days]) / 56) * 60, '1900-01-01') + DATEADD(MINUTE, duration / [days], '1900-01-01') TotalWorkingTime
FROM
    GetDriverCreditsByMonthYearBaseViewTrips(@startDate, @endDate )  option (optimize for (@startDate unknown, @endDate unknown))
```

**sproc DriverTripsByMonthYear**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DriverTripsByMonthYear
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @month INT,
    @year INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @startDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @endDate DATETIME

    SELECT @startDate = Dateadd(mm, ( @year - 1900 ) * 12 + @month - 1, 0 )
    SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, Dateadd(mm, ( @year - 1900 ) * 12 + @month, 0 ))

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT
        *,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, ((CONVERT(DECIMAL, Mileage) / [Days]) / 56) * 60, '1900-01-01') EstDrivingTimeDay,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, duration / [days], '1900-01-01') EstTimeOnSiteDay,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, ((CONVERT(DECIMAL, Mileage) / [Days]) / 56) * 60, '1900-01-01') + DATEADD(MINUTE, duration / [days], '1900-01-01') TotalWorkingTime
    FROM
        GetDriverCreditsByMonthYearBaseViewTrips(@startDate, @endDate )  option (optimize for (@startDate unknown, @endDate unknown))
END
GO
```

In summary, I need to convert month and year to DateTime and pass as parameters to an inline TVF without it taking 10x as long to execute.

**N.B** Both queries generate identical execution plans

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd do is check if you became a victim of [parameter sniffing](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/). If it's true, one of the ways to fix it would be to use

```
option (optimize for (@startDate unknown, @endDate unknown))
```

in the body of your TVF

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't make any difference. I initially thought might be parameter sniffing, but after some reading, it seems like it's not applicable to inline TVFs

Comment: Are you doing this inside the stored procedure?